# Repeating a function and groupint each output

Tags: r, dataframe, replication

I would like to run a function, eg: rexp(10), and I would like to repeat the function 3 times.

I know that this would be done by doing replicate(3,rexp(10)). However, how do I group the outputs (a vector of the 1st run of the function, then another separate vector of the 2nd run, and so on)?

Any help is much appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `replicate` has a `simplify` argument. Try setting it to `FALSE`

Comment: @markus Or even with the default `simplify=TRUE`, the output of `replicate(3,rexp(10))` is a matrix, the vectors are separated.

Comment: Not sure what exactly you mean by group the outputs? `mat <- replicate(3,rexp(10))` `mat[,1]` is group1, `mat[, 2]` is group2 and so on. What exactly are you looking for?

Comment: @RonakShah replicate(3,rexp(10)) means running the function rexp(10) 3 separate times am I right? What I mean by grouping the output means how do i get the output from the first run as 1 vector, 2nd run as 2nd vector and 3rd run as the 3rd vector. Or instead, how do you interpret my question?

Comment: That's what I showed above in my comment. `mat[,1]` is the 1st vector, `mat[, 2]` is the 2n vector and so on.